# Reference Request- Olech's article 1960

Tags: reference-request

I am looking for the following reference. Author C. Olech and,
[image]

It was cited by Philip Hartman's Ordinary differential equations, and could not find way to find it online.

If someone tell me how to find it online? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it referring to the  eighth 1960's publication of the Bull. Acad. Polon. Sci. Cl.? I would search online university libraries, else, you are going to have to go a University library that carries them.

Comment: For what it's worth, [MathSciNet](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=132228) has no link, neither to the journal nor to the article, so your best chance is probably to get a paper copy via a library.

Comment: For libraries closest to you that carry this journal, try the [WorldCat page for this journal](https://www.worldcat.org/title/bulletin-de-lacademie-polonaise-des-sciences-serie-des-sciences-mathematiques-astronomiques-et-physiques/oclc/1585821) and fill in the box "Enter your location" (use zip code if in the U.S.; I don't know to use if not U.S.). As far as I know, it's not yet been digitized and available online (even behind a paywall), at least not before 2004 (see [here](https://www.impan.pl/en/publishing-house/journals-and-series/bulletin-polish-acad-sci-math/all) for after 2003).